# How can get the unique id in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Need one unique id for my app. That unique id should never change. When the user uninstalls the app or kills the app it should not be changed. I have searched for something, but I don't need a UUID. I have decided to get the device token using this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability| UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    }

    return YES;
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings // NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}



- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken{


    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"content---%@", token);

}
```

There is one problem. In iOS 7 I got the device token constant, uninstalled the app and killed the app, and got the device token constant. But in iOS 8 and above the device token is not constant. When user kills the app, the device token changes. I need one unique device token for my app, or any other way to get the unique id. How can I fix this issue? Help me. Thanks advance.

Comment: You have to store the the id in a keychain so that when app is installed again you can fetch that id from keychain. This can be one method.

Comment: Check this tutorial you have to save UUID in Keychain. You can retrieve value even after delete app from device https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain

Comment: how i store id in a keychain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store the value in KeyChain like this.
Import "KeychainItemWrapper.h" in your AppDelegate.m file

Add these code in

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;`

```
//+++++++++++++++for unique identifier of the app++++++++++++++++
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"uniqueIdentifier"];

KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"MyUniqueId" accessGroup:nil];

NSString *strIdent;

if ([[keychainItem objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount] isEqualToString:@""]) {
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    NSLog(@"uniqueIdentifier=%@",uniqueIdentifier);
    [keychainItem setObject:uniqueIdentifier forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
    strIdent = [keychainItem objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:strIdent forKey:@"uniqueIdentifier"];



}else{
    strIdent=[keychainItem objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:strIdent forKey:@"uniqueIdentifier"];
}

NSLog(@"strIdent=%@",strIdent);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

//[keychainItem resetKeychainItem]; // to reset the keychain
```

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

KeychainItemWrapper.h

+++++++++++++++++++

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface KeychainItemWrapper : NSObject

// Designated initializer.
- (id)initWithIdentifier: (NSString *)identifier accessGroup:(NSString *)accessGroup;
- (void)setObject:(id)inObject forKey:(id)key;
- (id)objectForKey:(id)key;

// Initializes and resets the default generic keychain item data.
- (void)resetKeychainItem;

@end
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

KeychainItemWrapper.m

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
#define PASSWORD_USES_DATA

#import "KeychainItemWrapper.h"
#import <Security/Security.h>



@interface KeychainItemWrapper (PrivateMethods)

- (NSMutableDictionary *)secItemFormatToDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryToConvert;
- (NSMutableDictionary *)dictionaryToSecItemFormat:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryToConvert;

- (void)writeToKeychain;

@end

@implementation KeychainItemWrapper
{
NSMutableDictionary *keychainItemData;      // The actual keychain item data backing store.
NSMutableDictionary *genericPasswordQuery;  // A placeholder for the generic keychain item query used to locate the item.
}

- (id)initWithIdentifier: (NSString *)identifier accessGroup:(NSString *) accessGroup;
{
if (self = [super init])
{

    genericPasswordQuery = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [genericPasswordQuery setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [genericPasswordQuery setObject:identifier forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrGeneric];



    if (accessGroup != nil)
    {
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
        // Ignore the access group if running on the iPhone simulator.
        // 
        // Apps that are built for the simulator aren't signed, so there's no keychain access group
        // for the simulator to check. This means that all apps can see all keychain items when run
        // on the simulator.
        //
        // If a SecItem contains an access group attribute, SecItemAdd and SecItemUpdate on the
        // simulator will return -25243 (errSecNoAccessForItem).
#else           
        [genericPasswordQuery setObject:accessGroup forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessGroup];
#endif
    }

    // Use the proper search constants, return only the attributes of the first match.
    [genericPasswordQuery setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
    [genericPasswordQuery setObject:(__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes];

    NSDictionary *tempQuery = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:genericPasswordQuery];

    CFMutableDictionaryRef outDictionary = NULL;

    if (!(SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)tempQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&outDictionary) == noErr))
    {
        // Stick these default values into keychain item if nothing found.
        [self resetKeychainItem];

        // Add the generic attribute and the keychain access group.
        [keychainItemData setObject:identifier forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrGeneric];
        if (accessGroup != nil)
        {
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
            // Ignore the access group if running on the iPhone simulator.
            // 
            // Apps that are built for the simulator aren't signed, so there's no keychain access group
            // for the simulator to check. This means that all apps can see all keychain items when run
            // on the simulator.
            //
            // If a SecItem contains an access group attribute, SecItemAdd and SecItemUpdate on the
            // simulator will return -25243 (errSecNoAccessForItem).
#else           
            [keychainItemData setObject:accessGroup forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessGroup];
#endif
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // load the saved data from Keychain.
        keychainItemData = [self secItemFormatToDictionary:(__bridge NSDictionary *)outDictionary];
    }
    if(outDictionary) CFRelease(outDictionary);
}

return self;
}

- (void)setObject:(id)inObject forKey:(id)key 
{
if (inObject == nil) return;
id currentObject = [keychainItemData objectForKey:key];
if (![currentObject isEqual:inObject])
{
    [keychainItemData setObject:inObject forKey:key];
    [self writeToKeychain];
}
}

- (id)objectForKey:(id)key
{
 return [keychainItemData objectForKey:key];
}

- (void)resetKeychainItem
{
if (!keychainItemData) 
{
    keychainItemData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
else if (keychainItemData)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:keychainItemData];
#ifndef NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS
    OSStatus junk = 
#endif
        SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)tempDictionary);
    NSAssert( junk == noErr || junk == errSecItemNotFound, @"Problem deleting current dictionary." );
}

// Default attributes for keychain item.
[keychainItemData setObject:@"" forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
[keychainItemData setObject:@"" forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrLabel];
[keychainItemData setObject:@"" forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrDescription];

// Default data for keychain item.
#ifndef PASSWORD_USES_DATA
[keychainItemData setObject:@"" forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
#else
[keychainItemData setObject:[NSData data] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
#endif
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)dictionaryToSecItemFormat:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryToConvert
{
// The assumption is that this method will be called with a properly populated dictionary
// containing all the right key/value pairs for a SecItem.

// Create a dictionary to return populated with the attributes and data.
NSMutableDictionary *returnDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dictionaryToConvert];

// Add the Generic Password keychain item class attribute.
[returnDictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

// Convert the NSString to NSData to meet the requirements for the value type kSecValueData.
// This is where to store sensitive data that should be encrypted.
#ifndef PASSWORD_USES_DATA
// orig
NSString *passwordString = [dictionaryToConvert objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
[returnDictionary setObject:[passwordString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
#else
// DFH
id val = [dictionaryToConvert objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
if([val isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    val = [(NSString *)val dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
[returnDictionary setObject:val forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
#endif


return returnDictionary;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)secItemFormatToDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryToConvert
{
// The assumption is that this method will be called with a properly populated dictionary
// containing all the right key/value pairs for the UI element.

// Create a dictionary to return populated with the attributes and data.
NSMutableDictionary *returnDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dictionaryToConvert];

// Add the proper search key and class attribute.
[returnDictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];
[returnDictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

// Acquire the password data from the attributes.
CFDataRef passwordData = NULL;
if (SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)returnDictionary, (CFTypeRef *)&passwordData) == noErr)
{
    // Remove the search, class, and identifier key/value, we don't need them anymore.
    [returnDictionary removeObjectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];

#ifndef PASSWORD_USES_DATA
    // Add the password to the dictionary, converting from NSData to NSString.
    NSString *password = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[(__bridge NSData *)passwordData bytes] length:[(__bridge NSData *)passwordData length] 
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
#else
    NSData *password = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)passwordData;
    passwordData = NULL;
#endif
    [returnDictionary setObject:password forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
}
else
{
    // Don't do anything if nothing is found.
    NSAssert(NO, @"Serious error, no matching item found in the keychain.\n");
}
if(passwordData) CFRelease(passwordData);

return returnDictionary;
}

- (void)writeToKeychain
{
CFDictionaryRef attributes = NULL;
NSMutableDictionary *updateItem = nil;
OSStatus result;

if (SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)genericPasswordQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&attributes) == noErr)
{
    // First we need the attributes from the Keychain.
    updateItem = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(__bridge NSDictionary *)attributes];
    // Second we need to add the appropriate search key/values.
    [updateItem setObject:[genericPasswordQuery objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

    // Lastly, we need to set up the updated attribute list being careful to remove the class.
    NSMutableDictionary *tempCheck = [self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:keychainItemData];
    [tempCheck removeObjectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    // Remove the access group if running on the iPhone simulator.
    // 
    // Apps that are built for the simulator aren't signed, so there's no keychain access group
    // for the simulator to check. This means that all apps can see all keychain items when run
    // on the simulator.
    //
    // If a SecItem contains an access group attribute, SecItemAdd and SecItemUpdate on the
    // simulator will return -25243 (errSecNoAccessForItem).
    //
    // The access group attribute will be included in items returned by SecItemCopyMatching,
    // which is why we need to remove it before updating the item.
    [tempCheck removeObjectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessGroup];
#endif

    // An implicit assumption is that you can only update a single item at a time.
#ifndef NDEBUG      
    result = 
#endif
        SecItemUpdate((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)updateItem, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)tempCheck);

    NSAssert( result == noErr, @"Couldn't update the Keychain Item." );
}
else
{
    // No previous item found; add the new one.
    result = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)[self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:keychainItemData], NULL);
    NSAssert( result == noErr, @"Couldn't add the Keychain Item." );
}

if(attributes) CFRelease(attributes);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this I hope it would be helpful!!

```
NSString* Identifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]; 
NSLog(@"output is : %@", Identifier);
```

IN other ways you can do this!!

```
NSString *udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

Try with other Options!!

create your own unique ID and save it in the keychain.

use the vendor ID, which will be reset if all the app by the same vendor are removed from the device.

Comment: go through this link https://possiblemobile.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/ it might be very helpful whatever you want.